# resource id is nil after create - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I've got this in my seeds.rb

```
15.times do
  topic = Topic.create(
      name: Faker::Lorem.word,
  )
  color = topic.color_topic
  topic.update_attributes(color:color)
end
```

which calls this in the model

```
def color_topic # distributes color-0 thru color-4 equally through all topics
  puts self.id
  "color-#{self.id % 5}"
end
```

and I keep getting stuff like this

```
122
123
124
125
126
127
128
129
130

rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `%' for nil:NilClass
```

So is ruby running ahead of ActiveRecord's assigning of the id?
I thought this type of logic was used all the time.
What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any validations on `Topic`? You could always see what is created if you change the color line to `color = topic.color_topic if topic` to help debug.

Comment: you guessed it right - it was the name validation. I never imagined that Faker::Lorem would generate duplicate words so often. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of seeding data where you have uniqueness constraints, I wouldn't recommend leaving it up to random chance (ie. Faker::Lorem).  It's much easier to do something like:

```
(1..15).each do |i|
   topic = Topic.create(name: "name#{i}")
end
```

Also, as a sidenote, you may want to look into using factory girl to seed your data as it's far more powerful than the out of the box seeding framework: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl